# Navigation from one screen to another screen not working in android

Tags: android

```
public class check extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    void myonclick(View view)
    {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,check2.class);
         startActivity(mIntent);
    }
}


class check2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Welcome to second page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();  

    }
}
```

Hi. This is my code when I run this. When I click a button it will show error in emulator: The Application Check has stopped unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared both the activities in manifest file ?

The main activity should have the following intent-filter tag

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
```

The second activity to be declared as

```
<activity android:name="check2">
```

Also calling  finish() in the second activity would immediately return the control to the first activity.

Comment: one more question since there is only one main.xml suppose in my check2 suppose i want have other fields where should i have to do that..

Comment: @bharath - if this answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest File declare Two Activities like

```
<activity android:name=".LoginForm" android:label=" Login"/>
```

Here FrontPage is first file name
Here LoginForm is Second file name
Then When FrontPage file onclick the button the event will fire

code for that

```
           Intent userintent = new Intent(FrontPage.this, LoginForm.class);
    startActivity(userintent);
    finish();
```

Comment: thanks dude..i got it now..i didnt declared the activity in manifest.

Comment: one more question since there is only one main.xml suppose in my check2 suppose i want have other fields where should i have to do that.